# wxWidgets runtime error (Mismatch version)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, wxwidgets

I have a problem at start the program:

Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1010,wx containers,compatible with 2.8),

and your program used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1009,wx containers,compatible with 2.8).

My cmake settings:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(simple)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${wxWidgets_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++14")

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS net gl core base)

include("${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

Version of wxWidgets 3.0.3.

Comment: which OS/version/toolkit? Did you compile the library yourself?

Comment: I had two version of wxWidgets. I deleted once and it works great.

Answer (score 7):

If your desire is to have `__GXX_ABI_VERSION=1002`, specify `-fabi-version=2` to GCC.  To do this in your CMakeLists.txt, add:

```
add_definitions(-fabi-version=2)
```

This is a preferred approach compared to manually redefining `__GXX_ABI_VERSION`, which would violate C++ standards and potentially cause undefined behavior.

**Note**: `-fabi-version=2` may not always correspond to `__GXX_ABI_VERSION=1002` in future releases of GCC.  Compile and run this quick C++ program to check it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "__GXX_ABI_VERSION=" << __GXX_ABI_VERSION << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this way:

```
g++ -fabi-version=2 -o check_fabi_version check_fabi_version.cpp
```

Run this way:

```
./check_fabi_version
```

Example output as of GCC 8.2.0:

```
__GXX_ABI_VERSION=1002
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add to your program

```
#define __GXX_ABI_VERSION 1010
```

or just

```
sudo apt-get purge wx2.8-headers wx2.9-headers
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two version of wxWidgets instaled. I deleted one of them and it works great.